# The complement of any projective hyperplane is an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, projective-space, projective-schemes, zariski-topology

Studying algebraic geometry I'm in trouble with an assumption that my teacher uses:

Let $n\geq 1$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ be the projective n-dimensional space; suppose $H$ is the projective hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i T_i,$$
i.e. $H=\{(u_0:\cdots:u_n) \in \mathbb{P}^n \,:\, \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i u_i=0\}$.
Then $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus H$ (endowed with the induced Zariski topology of $\mathbb{P}^n$) is an affine variety.

I know that if $H=\{(u_0:\cdots:u_n) \in \mathbb{P}^n \,:\, u_0=0\}$, then the open subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$, $\mathbb{A}_{0}^{n}=\mathbb{P}^n\setminus H$ is an affine variety isomorphic to the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ trough the map $i_0: \mathbb{A}_{0}^{n} \longmapsto \mathbb{A}^n$ such that $i_0((u_0:\cdots:u_n))=(u_1/u_0,...,u_n/u_0)$ for all $(u_0:\cdots:u_n) \in \mathbb{A}_{0}^{n}$.

So it suffices to show that given any hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, then the complementary $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}_{0}^{n}$.

Any hint to construct this isomorphism? Is it possible otherwise to construct an isomorphism $f: \mathbb{P}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{P}^n$ that sends $H$ to $\mathbb{A}_{0}^{n}$??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A hint to construct an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^n$ sending $H$ to $\{u_0 = 0\}$, perhaps first consider how you would do this on $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k$. Everything here is linear algebra, to make things even more concrete you can even e.g. fix $n= 1$ or $2$ and play around with examples.

Comment: Let $H$ is the projective hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i T_i$, suppose $a_0 \neq 0$. Consider the map $f:\mathbb{P}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $$f((u_0:u_1:\cdots:u_n))=(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i u_i:u_1:\cdots:u_n).$$ I think this can be a solution.

Comment: Yes, and the inverse to $f$ should be $g(u_{0}:u_{1}:\cdots:u_{n})=(\frac{1}{a_{0}}(u_{0}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}u_{j}):u_{1}:\cdots:u_{n})$. It remains to show that $f$ and $g$ are inverse morphisms.